# Event trigger in javascript and conditional tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on uploading an image, I have javascript completely working. My javascript have functionality like shown in this image.

Now, when I call the image from database it just show on the place of "no image" (Image preview) and do not show the "change" and "Remove" button. please suggest something.

[image]

and here is my HTML code which looks like this...

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width:96%; height: 150px;">

        <img src="<?php if(isset($page->header_image)!= ""){echo $page->header_image;} else{ echo "http://www.placehold.it/280x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image";} ?>" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="width: 100%; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"><?php if(isset($page->header_image)!= ""){ echo "<img src='{$page->header_image}' />"; } ?></div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
        <input type="file" class="default" value="http://www.imafe.org/images/comext.jpg"/></span>
        <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript is here. http://www.websiteeonline.com/bootstrap-fileupload.js

now when i call the image from database it just show on the place of "no image" (Image preview) and do not show the "change" and "Remove" button.

Is there any suggestion for this?

Thank you!

Comment: if(isset($page->header_image)!= "") doesn't make sense as it will never be ""(instead it'll be just true or false), you just need to have if(isset($page->header_image))

Comment: No thats not the problem. Problem is "when I call the image from database it just show on the place of "no image" (Image preview) and do not show the "change" and "Remove" button. please suggest something."