# Get image name and path from input type=form

Tags: php

I am trying to get the value from a select field. But can not get the value of a file.

here is how code looks like:

```
 <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width:96%; height: 150px;">
        <img src="<?php if(isset($page->header_image)!= ""){echo $page->header_image;} else{ echo "http://www.placehold.it/280x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image";} ?>" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="width: 100%; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"><?php if(isset($page->header_image)!= ""){ echo "<img src='{$page->header_image}' />"; } ?></div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
        <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
        <input type="file" class="default" name="headerimage" /></span>
        <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is PHP code I am using.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-page'])){
    echo $_FILES['headerimage']['tmp_name'];
    echo $_FILES['headerimage']['name'];
}
```

but it's showing the following error: `undefined index "headerimage"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form tag, otherwise no files will be posted when you click submit and therefore $_FILES['headerimage'] will be undefined. e.g.

```
<form action="some page" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...your code...
</form>
```

Comment: It worked. I have form and it working like charm..Can you please look at this link also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878280/event-trigger-in-javascript-and-conditional-tag i am facing problem in this too. Thank you so much.

Comment: He didn't include any form tags in his example but how was he able to go past if(isset($_POST['submit-page'])) and fail with having $_FILES["headerimage"] undefined?

Comment: user3201500 if this worked for you can you accept this answer?

Comment: Its saying like i have to wait 3 min to tick your answer right. :) I want to tick your answer right. Thank you so much for your help.